# Accessing objects JSONArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I try to access throw different objects inside a JSONArray.
With this code: `console.log(array[0]);` the console shows me that array:

```
[Array[5]]
0: Array[5]
1: Array[2]
```

I try to acces that array and when i use this code to access the array `console.log(array[0][0]);` I access the first array and the console shows that:

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

After that when i do `console.log(array[0][1]);` to access the second array (Array[2]) then it says undefined.

Am I doing wrong accessing throw the general array to the others? What's the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: means you create a wrong/complex JSON.

Comment: @diEcho could you explain me more about it? :)

Comment: This should work... can you upload an example?

Comment: @Matt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671489/localhost-storage-jquery Here's the question I asked:)

Comment: I'm not sure why it returns undefined, but you'd need `console.log(array[1][0]);` to access Array[2]. (Rather than `array[0][1]`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to `JSON.stringify(array[0][1])` to see what's inside.. Maybe it's malformed in some way.

The same way you can view the objects, which in your case should be `console.log(JSON.stringify(array[0][0][0]));` for example.